# What performance issues are there with running sum in SQL server vs handling it in the code?

Tags: sql, view

I'm working on a project an since it was my first attempt on ef and i wasn't quite sure how to go on about certain things like calculation i used SQL calculated field to handle row sums (quantity * price) and some SQL Views that calculate Sum()

in the old days I would fire up a view or a stored procedure

**UPDATE**

I think what was being asked was whether to use a hybrid solution to calculate rows inside SQL or whether to shift it to code and handle that on webserver?

**result**
I carried on using sql server option, however moving to nosql I now know I should have had it handled by the application's code as that would make it more versatile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My experience is that databases are extremely fast at this sort of thing since they are heavily optimized for these operations.

Also, consider the alternative.  Say you want to calculate SUM(quantity * price) for a 50,000 row result set (nevermind the table size, let's just say your query was 50k rows big).  If you did it in your app you'd have to retrieve 50k pairs of integers (let's just assume they're ints, and 32bit at that - which they probably aren't).  So that's 64bits per row, and 50k rows, gives us 3.2M bits, or 400KB of data.

Now the DB has to spit that to your app over the network, your app has to wait for the data, read it all into some data structure, and then iterate over it.  The network transfer time for that operation is going to obliterate any savings you might have had by doing the calculation in your app.

By contrast if the DB does the sum you have to transfer a lot less data.  You may also have some benefits if you're able to cache queries on the DB size (this is vendor specific, of course).

In a nutshell - unless you have a really good reason to do this sort of thing in your app, just leave it to the DB and save yourself the headache.